# react-redux form validate is not working and submitting form data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

i am using `react-redux-form` 7.2.3 to create a form and submit. the values submitted are taken from the `initialValues` set in the config and not taken from the form itself in the browser. I added validate function but if i dont set the `initialValues` then the validate never passes. i cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. do i need to set the `initValues` manually `onChange` everytime?

```
class SecurityExemptionsNew extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleShowError = this.handleShowError.bind(this);
        this.initData = this.initData.bind(this);
        this.renderSelectField = this.renderSelectField.bind(this);
        this.renderTextField = this.renderTextField.bind(this);
        this.updateCommsMatrix = this.updateCommsMatrix.bind(this);
        this.renderSelect2Field = this.renderSelect2Field.bind(this);
        this.clearValue = this.clearValue.bind(this);
        this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
        this.getCommsmatrices = this.getCommsmatrices.bind(this);
        this.fnToggleCheckboxes = this.fnToggleCheckboxes.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedValues = this.handleCheckedValues.bind(this);
        this.meta = {
            title: 'Request Exemption',
            description: 'This section allows you to request an exemption'
        };
        this.passMetaBack = this.passMetaBack.bind(this);
        this.runOnce = false;
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            isLoading: true,
            searchable: true,
            selectValue: { value: '0', label: 'All'},
            selectMarketValue : "Group Enterprise Technology (GET)",
            clearable: true,
            rtl: false,
            options: [
                { value: '0', label: 'All'}
                ],
            toggleChecked: true,
            lm_security_engineer: '',
            select_exemption_type: 'Security',
            select_market: 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)',
            select_service_domain: 'Corporate (Internal/External)',
            select_service_id: '0',
            select_security_engineer: null,
            select_business_priority: 'Low'
        };
        this.exemptionType = {};
        this.markets = {};
        this.serviceDomain = {};
        this.servicesList = {};
        this.matrices = {};
        this.securityEngineerList = {};
        this.securityEngineerLocalMarketList = {}
        this.businessPriority = {}
        this.tableOptions = {
                paginationShowsTotal: false,
                sizePerPageList: [ {
                    text: '10', value: 10
                  }, {
                    text: '50', value: 50
                  }, {
                      text: '100', value: 100
                    } 
                  ],
            };
        this.checkedValues = [];
    }
componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount");
        this.passMetaBack;
        //this.props.initialize({ market: 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)' });
        //this.props.dispatch(change('SecurityExemptionsNewForm', 'market', 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)'));
    }
renderTextField(field) {
        let value = '';
        let readonly = false
        if (field.label == 'Requestor') {
            value = this.props.activeUser.email;
            readonly = true;
        }
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="control-label col-sm-2">{field.label}</label>
                <div className="col-sm-10">
                    <input
                        name={field.input.name}
                        className="form-control form-control-inline"
                        type="text"
                        {...field.text}
                        defaultValue={value}
                        readOnly={readonly}
                    />
                </div>
                    {field.meta.error}
            </div>
        );
    }
   onSubmit(values){
        console.log(values);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this);
        if (!this.runOnce && this.props.isReady) {
            this.runOnce = true;
            this.initData();
        }
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        let form = 'Loading...';
        if (this.state.loaded) {
            let policiesTable = this.renderPolicies();
            return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))} className="form-horizontal">
                        <Field
                            label="Type"
                            loadFrom="exemptionType"
                            name="exemption_type"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Market"
                            loadFrom="markets"
                            name="market"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Service Domain"
                            loadFrom="serviceDomain"
                            name="service_domain"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                            type="select"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Service/Project/Programme"
                            loadFrom="servicesList"
                            name="service_id"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                            type="select"
                        />

                        <Field
                            label="Demand Ref"
                            name="demand_ref"
                            component={this.renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Exemption Summary"
                            name="name"
                            component={this.renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Exemption Description"
                            name="description"
                            component={this.renderTextareaField}
                            type="textarea"
                        />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="control-label col-sm-2">Comms Matrix:</label>
                            <div className="col-sm-4">

                                <Async 
                                    multi={false} 
                                    value={this.state.selectValue} 
                                    onChange={this.updateValue} 
                                    valueKey="value" 
                                    labelKey="label" 
                                    loadOptions={this.getCommsmatrices} 
                                    onValueClick={this.gotoCommsmatrix}
                                    cache={false}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {policiesTable}
                        <Field
                            label="Requestor"
                            name="requestor"
                            component={this.renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                            readonly="readonly"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Security Engineer"
                            loadFrom="securityEngineerList"
                            name="security_engineer"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                            type="select"
                        />
                        {this.state.lm_security_engineer}
                        <Field
                            label="Link to Design Doc"
                            name="designdoc"
                            component={this.renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Business Priority"
                            loadFrom="businessPriority"
                            name="business_priority"
                            component={this.renderSelectField}
                            type="select"
                        />
                        <Field
                            label="Expiry date (dd-MMM-yy)"
                            name="expiry_date"
                            component={this.renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" className="btn btn-vodafone hidden-print">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return <div className="container-fluid">{form}</div>;
    }
}
SecurityExemptionsNew = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    SecurityExemptionsNew
); 
function validate (values) {
    console.log(values);
    const errors = {};

    if(!values.exemption_type){
        errors.exemption_type = "Select exemption type";
    }
    if(!values.market){
        errors.market = "select market";
    }
    if(!values.service_domain){
        errors.service_domain = "select service domain";
    }
    if(!values.service_id){
        errors.service_id = "Select a service";
    }
    if(!values.name){
        errors.name = "Enter summary";
    }

    return errors;
}
    export default reduxForm({
        form: 'SecurityExemptionsNewForm', // a unique name for this form
        validate,
        initialValues: { 
            exemption_type: 'Security',
            market: 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)', 
            service_domain: 'Corporate (Internal/External)',
            service_id: '0',
            name: 'test',
            security_engineer: '',
            business_priority: 'Low'
        }
    })(SecurityExemptionsNew);
```

I have also tried

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'SecurityExemptionsNewForm', // a unique name for this form
    validate,
    initialValues: { 
        exemption_type: 'Security',
        market: 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)', 
        service_domain: 'Corporate (Internal/External)',
        service_id: '0',
        name: 'test',
        security_engineer: '',
        business_priority: 'Low'
    }
})(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SecurityExemptionsNew)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the order must be

**1. reduxForm**

```
let form = reduxForm({
        form: 'SecurityExemptionsNewForm', // a unique name for this form
        validate,
        initialValues: { 
            exemption_type: 'Security',
            market: 'Group Enterprise Technology (GET)', 
            service_domain: 'Corporate (Internal/External)',
            service_id: '0',
            name: 'test',
            security_engineer: '',
            business_priority: 'Low'
        }
    })(SecurityExemptionsNew);
```

**2. Connect()**

```
SecurityExemptionsPage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form);
```

**3. Export**

```
export { SecurityExemptionsPage as SecurityExemptionsNew };
```

Comment: problem is when i change the values of the input the only thing that gets validated and submitted is the data in `initialValues`. this example does not work